# Show that any two different functions in $C(\Omega)$ differ as generalized functions as well.

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, distribution-theory

Show that any two different functions in $C(\Omega)$ differ as generalized functions as well.

Let $f,g \in C(\Omega)$. Since $f\ne g$, there is a $x_0 \in \Omega$ such that $f(x_0)\ne g(x_0)$. Hence there exists a neighborhood say ($U_{x_0}$). Let's say $h(x)=f(x)-g(x) \gt 0$ for all $x$ in $U_{x_0}$. Let $K$ be a compact set in $U_{x_0}$ There exists $\phi \in D(\Omega)$ such that $\phi=1$ on $K$ and $0$ outside $U_{x_0}$. Since $K$ is compact, there is a $\delta \gt 0$ such that $h(x) \gt 0$ in $k$. Then $(T_h,\phi)$ on $K$ is $\int_{k}(f(x)-g(x))\phi(x) dx \ne 0$. Hence $\int_{U_{x_0}}f(x)\phi(x)dx \ne \int_{U_{x_0}}g(x)\phi(x)dx$. Thus they differ as generalized functions as well.

The only question is how DO I get hold of the compact set $K$?? Since $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^d}$, I can do that. What if $\Omega$ is any other space??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You need $K$ to be compact and have nonzero volume. If $\Omega$ is a subset of an infinite dimensional vectorspace, you [may have other problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite-dimensional_Lebesgue_measure)

Comment: @s.harp In here this is the only way or is there any other way?

Comment: Can you add the definition of a generalised function and define $D()$? It might help.

Comment: @NeerajKumar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)

Comment: It seems rather strange to have a whole derivation in $\mathbb{R}$ and later ask for the case when we have any arbitrary 'space'. For example you need to have that $f$ maps to $\mathbb{R}$ else the whole point of 'ordering' $f(x)-g(x)>0$ is lost and then you'll have to start the derivation afresh. Perhaps it would be nice if you would specify what kind of 'space' $\Omega$ is. You need topology (for continuity), measure (for integration), total order (for the steps in your derivation), etc...

Comment: Also one way around the 'order' condition is to introduce a metric and say $|f(x)-g(x)|>0$ instead of just $f(x)-g(x)>0$. In that particular case, the answer is if the metric space is **locally compact**. (Since then, in any neighbourhood of a point, one has a compact set $K$ inside it.)